# How to Remove \n and \r from JSON string using Bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I've been trying to remove the new line and carriage return indicators from my JSON output using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866608/regex-for-json-file-with-multiple-piping).

I've also tried running this based on another answer I've seen on Stack Overflow, but it still does not appear to be working:

```
 sed -E ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r{0,1}\n/\\n/g' text.json > text_clean.json
```

My current `.sh` script looks like this:

```
getPage() {
curl --fail -X GET 'https://api.test.com/v1/marx?page=1&pageSize=1000&sort=desc' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'  
}

getPage \
| jq -c '.data[]' \
  > text.json
```

What am I missing here?

If it helps, an example of the string containing it takes on many different forms in the output, but here's a good one:

`Ok! Thank you so much.\r\nBest,\r\nClaire\r\n\r\n`

Comment: @Emma I have tried applying that methodology and it still does not work :(

Comment: @Emma I will run `sed -i 's/\r//g' text.json` and it won't really do anything

Comment: @gooponyagrinch If you have `perl` installed, you may be able to get the result you expect from `echo "Ok! Thank you so much.\r\nBest,\r\nClaire\r\n\r\n" | perl -pe 's/\r\n//g'`

Comment: @gooponyagrinch Or by using `tr`:  `echo "Ok! Thank you so much.\r\nBest,\r\nClaire\r\n\r\n" | tr -d '\r\n'`

Comment: It'd be helpful if we actually could see literal inputs. If the newlines you want to remove are non-literal and within JSON strings, I'd be telling `jq` to do the removal.

Comment: @Jebby, `tr` operates on individual characters, so if it's parsing your input to remove a literal backslash (followed by a `r` or `n` or not), it'll also remove a literal `n` and a literal `r` on their own.

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to modify JSON, do it in `jq`.**

In this case, that might mean changing:

```
getPage \
| jq -c '.data[]' \
> text.json
```

...to...

```
getPage \
| jq -c '.data[] | sub("\r\n"; " ") | sub("\n"; " ")' \
> text.json
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `tr` for this.

In you example, try the following:

```
 echo "Ok! Thank you so much.\r\nBest,\r\nClaire\r\n\r\n"| tr -d '\012\015'
```

Comment: This presumes those are literal control characters; but as I understand it the OP is actually dealing with literal backslash followed by literal `r` or `n` to represent these characters in JSON.

Comment: Just used the same example he is using, but still, even if literal or not, it should still work in bash script.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the characters by using `perl` if you have it installed:

```
echo "Ok! Thank you so much.\r\nBest,\r\nClaire\r\n\r\n" | perl -pe 's/\r\n//g'
```

Comment: `perl` is safe for the job. `tr` is not.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the tip. I removed the example for `tr`.