# using Github actions matrix job with dynamically build .json

Tags: json, shell, github, github-actions

So i have a github actions that fetches a json and then extracts a specific field into a new json array using

```
jq -r '[.hits[].id]'
```

which results in this file: https://github.com/Jodsderechte/Jodsderechte.github.io/blob/main/Data/WaList_Converted.json

however if i try to use that in a matrix job using

```
${{fromJson(needs.setup.outputs.wa_List)}}
```

i get

Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'Request'. .github/workflows/RequestWagoData.yml (Line: 67, Col: 19): Error parsing fromJson,.github/workflows/RequestWagoData.yml (Line: 67, Col: 19): Error parsing fromJson,.github/workflows/RequestWagoData.yml (Line: 67, Col: 19): Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.,.github/workflows/RequestWagoData.yml (Line: 67, Col: 19): Unexpected value ''

I guess this is because of the newlines but i'm not sure. i tried like a million different things trying to follow the advice in
[How to Remove \n and \r from JSON string using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54798272/how-to-remove-n-and-r-from-json-string-using-bash)
and
[Github Actions: How use strategy/matrix with script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977364/github-actions-how-use-strategy-matrix-with-script)

but i can't for the live of me figure it out

https://github.com/Jodsderechte/Jodsderechte.github.io/edit/main/.github/workflows/RequestWagoData.yml here is the whole action including my history of 300 failed atempts of getting this to work

Comment: It might indeed be related to the new lines. Did you try informing the JSON hardcoded in the matrix strategy as it is, and then without breaking lines to check?

Comment: `-c` with `jq` will give you the compact JSON without newlines.

Comment: In `jq -r '[.hits[].id]' << fetch-api-data-action/WeakAurasList.json  >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`, the output parameter name is missing i.e. `wa_List`. What is `content` [here](https://github.com/Jodsderechte/Jodsderechte.github.io/blob/main/.github/workflows/RequestWagoData.yml#LL24C1-L24C1)?

Comment: i did hardcode the json into the matrix strategy and it works then yeah i'll try that -c thanks!

Comment: @Azeem content is the result of using https://github.com/jaywcjlove/github-action-read-file to read in the json file. that is just something i tried that is supposed to read the json and make it available

Comment: Right. Seems like something that you experimented with. Your recent [update](https://github.com/Jodsderechte/Jodsderechte.github.io/blob/main/.github/workflows/RequestWagoData.yml#L37) doesn't look right. Given your current configuration, it should be something like this: `run: echo "content=$(jq -r -c '[.hits[].id]' << fetch-api-data-action/WeakAurasList.json)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`. Here, `content` is the array of `id`s. You need to set `id` for this step to access it in the `outputs`. See [Defining outputs for jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs).

Comment: @Azeem but the step of that job has an id . i also tried your solution. i even tried printing using echo but all i'm getting is echo "" so somethign is still not right

Comment: This file path `fetch-api-data-action/WeakAurasList.json` is not correct. It should be [`./Data/WeakAurasList.json`](https://github.com/Jodsderechte/Jodsderechte.github.io/blob/main/Data/WeakAurasList.json) that's where it's located in your repo. And, that `<< file` needs to be `< file`.

Comment: @Azeem <file and >Output or <file and >> output? also the /data/WeakAurasList.json only gets written after the step  Build and Deploy and it is as mentioned in https://github.com/JamesIves/fetch-api-data-action in fetch-api-data-action/

Comment: Or, if you're not using that file then you must be referring to the output of the steps [`fetchData`](https://github.com/Jodsderechte/Jodsderechte.github.io/blob/main/.github/workflows/RequestWagoData.yml#L26) then it should be handled accordingly i.e. `run: echo "content=$(jq -r -c '[.hits[].id]' < ./WeakAurasList)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`.

Comment: Looks like your workflow is all mixed at this point i.e. API output and the sample files. You might want to clean that up first.

Comment: that results in /home/runner/work/_temp/27b5ceca-1570-4bc8-8a19-17e3e6689486.sh: line 1: ./WeakAurasList: No such file or directory

But i cleaned it up it should now be better to read

Comment: Add `.json` extension. That action adds the extension to file name. See https://github.com/JamesIves/fetch-api-data-action#optional-choices.

Comment: the whole data should also exist in env.fetch-api-data tried using that instead 

https://github.com/Jodsderechte/Jodsderechte.github.io/actions/runs/5278980602/jobs/9549039260 but that resulted in /home/runner/work/_temp/40b2debc-59a3-4f48-936c-0ebdbed45e52.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Comment: Missing closing double quote after file name [here](https://github.com/Jodsderechte/Jodsderechte.github.io/actions/runs/5279007003/jobs/9549100152#step:5:2).

Comment: ok and with

Run echo "content=$(jq -r -c '[.hits[].id]' < ./WeakAurasList.json >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

i got 
/home/runner/work/_temp/f1a37079-05ae-4b4b-90cc-010c9d2334c7.sh: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.

https://github.com/Jodsderechte/Jodsderechte.github.io/actions/runs/5279007003/jobs/9549100152

Comment: ok back to 


Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job 'Request'. .github/workflows/RequestWagoData.yml (Line: 58, Col: 19): Error parsing fromJson,.github/workflows/RequestWagoData.yml (Line: 58, Col: 19): Error parsing fromJson,.github/workflows/RequestWagoData.yml (Line: 58, Col: 19): Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.,.github/workflows/RequestWagoData.yml (Line: 58, Col: 19): Unexpected value '' 


now

Comment: and thats the workflow run for that error https://github.com/Jodsderechte/Jodsderechte.github.io/actions/runs/5279113814/jobs/9549341773

Comment: Try: `echo "content=$(jq '[.hits[].id] | @json' <<< ${{env.fetch-api-data}})" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"`. With file, you need `< file`, with string you need `<<< string`. Also, for `fromJson`, you need escaped JSON i.e. observe `@json` with `jq`.

Comment: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6

https://github.com/Jodsderechte/Jodsderechte.github.io/actions/runs/5279237680/jobs/9549621292

Comment: Here's your working [workflow](https://github.com/iamazeem/Jodsderechte.github.io/actions/runs/5279642375/workflow). Changes: `echo "content=$(jq -c '[.hits[].id]' < "./fetch-api-data-action/WeakAurasList.json")" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"` and `WeakAura: ${{ fromJson(needs.setup.outputs.wa_list) }}`

Comment: thank you! it also was that i previously used ${{ env.steps.createList.outputs.content }}
instead of ${{ steps.createList.outputs.content }} meaning everything i tried couldn't even work anyways

Comment: Yes, that `env.steps` was an issue too. You're welcome! I'll delete that fork shorty.

Comment: Full [workflow](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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).